# How to check formal argument of a method are empty or null in java

Tags: java

```
public void display(String name,int age,double percentage)
{
}
```

How to check if the values of `name`, `age` and `percentage` are `null` or empty.

Comment: Primitives can't be null or empty.

Comment: `if (name == null)` ?

Comment: Primitives cannot be null. Either define a range of values that are valid for each and test against that, or just require that data always be provided and you won't have to bother with these kinds of checks. Don't use the corresponding object classes to get around it since you'll cause a NullPointerException if they ever get unboxed.

Comment: For the String name, you can use StringUtils from apache commons-lang: `StringUtils.isEmpty(name)` will check for null or empty.

Comment: Actually my question is if there are any no, of argument of any type how to check it is empty or null

Comment: There are no Java methods which accept "any number of arguments of any type", this is not a valid method signature. If you want to state your question more precisely, consider updating your posting above.

Answer (score 1):

**String name**: may be null and may be "" (empty)

**int age**: Cannot be null, it may be 0 (empty)

**double percentage**: Cannot be null, it may be 0.0 (empty) or NaN

So basically the code below would check all input parameters and throw an exception if any of them are null or "empty"

```
public void display(String name, int age, double percentage) {
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty() || age == 0 || percentage == 0.0 || Double.isNaN(percentage)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is null or empty");
    }
    ... do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Maybe add whether double isNaN. That's not "null", but a "NaN" looks to me much more invalid than a harmless zero.

Comment: I agree. It really depends what you define as "empty". I have included a nan check in the code and it is up to the reader to use which checks he wants.

Comment: Hello, my name is `"  "` and my age is `-20`. I can call this method with no problems.

Comment: @Kayaman that is a valid question, however that is not what the original question is. He mentions null and empty... not blank or semantically invalid.

Comment: Yes, but he's also talking about "empty or null" with regards to primitives, so we can't take his question at face value.